# Can you require Stripe Connect accounts to be held by people in the US?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, geolocation, stripe-payments, tax

I'm integrating with Stripe Connect, and, for tax purposes, only want to support Connected Accounts for people in the US.

I wasn't able to find anything about this in the documentation. Is there a mechanism for this?

I'm using Firebase, so an alternative pattern I've considered is gating Google accounts US IPs, but that seems like a very error-prone process.

Comment: How are the Connect Accounts being created?  Are these existing Stripe Accounts you are connecting to?  Connect has multiple integration paths with different capabilities.  Understanding which one(s) you are considering using will help get your question answered.

Comment: @RyanM I'm using [this flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-account) to programmatically create an Express Connect account, and redirecting the user to the dashboard to fill out their account info and stuff. Just now, getting this link for you, I noticed there's a "Country" field in `stripe.accounts.create` which looks quite promising.

Answer (score 1):

You have mostly answered your own question but I'll just add this here to help others.

Since you are programmatically creating the accounts, my approach would be to notify your users that you are only able to support US based entities up front, then hard code the `country` code that you pointed out in [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-account).

Additional information about the `country` parameter can be found in the [API reference doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-country):

> The country in which the account holder resides, or in which the business is legally established. This should be an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. For example, if you are in the United States and the business for which you’re creating an account is legally represented in Canada, you would use CA as the country for the account being created. Available countries include Stripe’s global markets as well as countries where cross-border payouts are supported.

Comment: How does setting the `country` param to US prevent non-US entities from using it? What happens if someone creates an account but hasn't provided SSN or anything yet, and I pay out to them, and it turns out they're not actually a US entity or something? I'm new to payment processing and taxation considerations, so just trying to get a good mental model for all this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Setting it doesn't. But when they go through the hosted onboarding they will have to supply identity documents.  I recommend doing this yourself with some test accounts to get a feel for the process.